# Hourglass in grails

Tags: grails

I have a Grails app that downloads a file that's generated from a database query that takes about a minute. How can I implement a sort of hourglass (or something prettier)  so the user knows the request is being processed ?

The corresponding link calls a controller method that does the processing and uses the **response** object.

Comment: Do you want to try to show the actual progress of the request, or just a notification that it's 'working on it'? The latter is pretty simple, see this similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743262/showing-spinner-gif-in-ajax-call-on-loading-time-in-grails

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to do something like a spinner notification while an operation is being processed.

you can check [this](http://juddsolutions.blogspot.com/2008/08/enabling-ajax-spinner-in-grails.html) out